# Time series visualization with status update for multiple attributes

Tags: charts, visualization, data-analysis, user-experience

Below is the sample data. I Need to plot a chart to visualize status changes for multiple attributes over a period of time. Below are the additional points the visualization should handle. I am not looking for any specific charting solution to implement the visualization but rather get an idea of how this can be handled.

In the below data, there are three attributes(r1,r2,r3), but I could have up to 30. 
For each attribute, the status can be Pass/Fail/Error for a given month (period). 
There could be as many as 100 months of data to plot.

```
Request,Date,Status
r1,Jan, Pass
r2,Jan, Pass
r3,Jan, Fail
r1,Feb, Pass
r2,Feb, Fail
r3,Feb, Pass
r1,Mar, Pass
r2,Mar, Error
r3,Mar, Pass
r1,Apr, Pass
r2,Apr, Error
r3,Apr, Fail
```

r1,r2,r3 are student results each month.

Comment: So, you've been a member for ten years and still haven't learned [ask]? Care to define which application you would like to use, or should we tell you to buy a box of crayons? What does a data point for `r1/Pass` look like on a chart?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a line/bar plot :

```
code Pass/Fail/Error with 0,1,2 and plot it on y axis,
on x axis put R1/R2/R3 stacked with date, even if you have 100 months
you have to put a switch where you can choose the month
```

By the way your question is too vague...what are R1,R2,R3? it seems that is something that must be put in production

Comment: Ability to view over a period(multiple months) of time is important. Is there any any other  approach ?